# stop checking code syntax after some command?

Tags: php

```
echo $a;

exit();
die();

eecho $b;  // line 40
```

`Error - syntax error on line 40...`

Why `exit` or `die` don't work in such a case?
How to stop checking code syntax after some command?

Comment: Syntax checking happens before any code is run.  It has to try and make sense of the whole code to know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: you used eecho instead of echo?

Comment: @BehzadDadashpour - once again - `How to stop checking code syntax after some command ?` - that is the question.

Comment: @NigelRen, in javascript there is `return` - it breaks everything after that line - whatever syntax is there. Are you really sure there is no such a command in `php`?

Comment: @BehzadDadashpour that is probably just an example. OP did just as expected of a question an MVCE.

Comment: @puerto javascript won't work as well if there is a syntax error. As an example `function foobar() { return "test"; *- }` will not work, even if there is a `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method you can use is to comment the rest of the code.

```
echo $a;
/* Comment rest of the file 
exit();
die();

eecho $b;  // line 40
```

Or if you want to "enable" the code on line 41 again you put `*/` to stop the comment.
You don't have to put a `*/` in the code if you only use it for debugging (as I do).
It will create an notice:

> Warning: Unterminated comment starting line 4 in /in/jkqu0 on line 4

But as long as it's only debugging then it's no harm done.
https://3v4l.org/jkqu0

Comment: This can do it, you have to be careful that you don't have other similar comments in your code, otherwise the `*/` will end the comment.

Comment: Good point. If that happens you will get an error and it's easily spotted since most IDEs show comments in a different color.

Answer (score 0):

eecho $b; ????
Because php script execution works that way. php parser first check for php syntax in the script if it found any error it throws it before interpret it.
Steps of php script execution.
Lexing
Parsing
Compilation
Interpretation

Comment: You need two spaces to make an enter do a new line on SO.